# How to Return Git Files to Original Folders

Tags: git, macos

So I am fairly new to Git, and I did something quite stupid.  I added git to a directory which contained many other directories. I then used add *.CPP to add files, not realizing it would pull them out of the subdirectories.  Everything is now disorganized and I need to send the files to my boss.  I just want to return everything to the way it was before I started messing around with git.

Sorry for the stupidity, I'm a complete idiot!
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: What is the exact command you ran? `git add` shouldn't change anything in the working tree.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you committed your work before 'using add *.CPP', `git reset --hard` will restore your files and directories.

Comment: Thank you so much; you are a life saver!

Comment: Is there any way to git something while keeping it in the original folder?